# Can I interact with different components of my 3d model in React js - Three Fiber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, 3d, blender, react-three-fiber

I have 3d sphere and links around as different mesh component. Can i rotate links mesh around my sphere without this sphere?

[My 3d model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Z51.jpg)

I want to interact separately with links mesh and sphere mesh and rotate separately sphere and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u use gltf to jsx https://gltf.pmnd.rs/ , you can then use:

```
<mesh onClick={handleClick}/>
```

The model will be decomposed in to declarative parts, you can modify one by one after.

To rotate some part of the mesh via drag, the easiest would be to useGesture package , the basic pipeline is like this:

```
// mesh / object reference 
const ref = useRef()
// cursor movement XY delta
const delta = useRef(null)

useFrame(() => {
  if (delta !== null)
    ref.current.rotation.set([delta.x,delta.y, 0])
})

return ( <…
  <mesh ref={ref}/>
…/>)
```

pls note that you need to set `delta.current = { x, y }`
yourself somewhere

That example with drag https://use-gesture.netlify.app/docs/options/#transform

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But if i want to rotate some component by scroll event? How i can get instance of component for interact with it?

Is it possible to get instance from gltf model like: 
<code>
import model from "./sphere.gltf";
let mesh = model.nameMesh;
useFrame((state, delta) => (mesh.current.rotation.y -= 0.1001 * Math.PI / 180));
</code>

Comment: Yes it’s should be possible but you have to do back traversal.  The gltf to jsx makes it much simpler. It will give you this primitives you can ref to

Comment: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltf-accessing-meshes-from-an-imported-scene/1845/2 This how back traversal looks (not sure if that’s a case for you)

Comment: Thank you, i already found solution by output all object into console and i done it by this code: useFrame((state, delta) => (ref.current.children[1].rotation.y -= 0.1001 * Math.PI / 180));

Comment: but maybe traversal better then get by object like i'm do above or that's doesn't care?

Comment: @SergeySamokhvalov glad you sort it!

Answer (score 1):

allright allright allright, i'm found solution and i want to thank @antokhio that he made me think :)

My solution:

```js
useFrame((state, delta) => (ref.current.children[0].rotation.y -= 0.1001 * Math.PI / 180));
useFrame((state, delta) => (ref.current.children[1].rotation.z += 0.1001 * Math.PI / 180));
```

as you can see we are simply get children from object that have components of your 3d object. So... That's all! Thank you!